# Remove debugger keyword during compilation in google closure

Tags: gulp, google-closure-compiler, google-closure

**UPDATE:**
**The JS version of closure-compiler is no longer supported or maintained.**
https://github.com/google/closure-compiler-npm/blob/master/packages/google-closure-compiler-js/readme.md

---

Im trying to find if there is a way to remove the "debugger" keyword during compilation process, im using the javascript version [google-closure-compiler](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-closure-compiler) with gulp.

Looking through the documentation it is clear we can set the flag to stop/show error messages during compilation by doing the following.

https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Flags-and-Options

```
--jscomp_off
```

translating this to gulp, it is:

```
const googleClosureOptions = {
  ...
  jscomp_error:"checkDebuggerStatement"
}
```

however this works on stopping the compilation by throwing error or to show a warning.

```
zyxcdafg.js:1444: ERROR - [JSC_DEBUGGER_STATEMENT_PRESENT] Using the debugger statement can halt your application if the user has a JavaScript debugger running.
                    debugger;
                    ^^^^^^^^^
```

but what I am trying to achieve is to remove the debugger keyword. Is this possible to achieve using googleclosure. I can not find any flags or options relating to this.

---

**UPDATE:**
**The JS version of closure-compiler is no longer supported or maintained.**
https://github.com/google/closure-compiler-npm/blob/master/packages/google-closure-compiler-js/readme.md

Comment: You would need to create a custom pass for it. I've sometimes wondered about using our refactoring framework matching to replace custom passes.

Comment: @John Seems making more than one pass is the way to go here, but it is redundant, there should be an option for this sort of thing.

Comment: redundant to what?   You could also maintain a patch to one of the peephole passes.  If you are familiar with how those passes work, it would be trivial.  It isn't likely to be something that would be accepted upstream though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No I don't think so. I'd suggest you use something else to do it. Like `sed`:

```
find dist -name "*.js" -exec sed -i 's/\sdebugger;//' {} +
```

Something like that will `find` files in your `dist` folder that **end with `.js`** and then `exec`-ute `sed` to replace all instances of `debugger;` with  nothing.

You could add that to a script that calls your Closure Compiler build.

Comment: I feared I would have to resort to this.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler doesn't have a command-line api for defining custom code removal passes, but the compiler's architecture does allow for registering custom passes and a pass to remove a debugger statement should be trivial:

```
    if (n.isDebugger()) {
        compiler.reportChangeToEnclosingScope(n);
        n.detach();
    }
```

The general structure would follow:

https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/blob/master/src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/CheckDebuggerStatement.java